# Page Refresh Returns to previous page

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I am using server.transfer to redirect from one to another page... 
lets say when i click on button1 of page1 i redirects to page2 using server.transfer
but than when i refresh that page2 , it get postback and redirects me page1 again..
 please tell me where i am doing wrong.?
I have tried with both.. but result is same

```
server.Transfer("~/admin/mypage.aspx?msg=A",False  )
server.Transfer("~/admin/mypage.aspx?msg=A",True  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `Server.Transfer`, the browser will not know that you are showing page2, it still thinks that you are showing page1. This is the reason why the browser will refresh page1 instead of page2.

If you use `Response.Redirect` instead, the server will explicitly tell the browser to load page2 and shouldn't have this problem anymore.

There are several articles explaining the difference between `Server.Transfer` and `Response.Redirect`, you can find some on [google](http://tinyurl.com/ybmdqhd).

Comment: is their any solution for this?

Comment: "If you use `Response.Redirect` instead..."